# Polymer: core-dropdown-overlay update size on model change

Tags: polymer

When I use the paper-menu-button to create a overlay with paper-items I noticed that the size of the resulting core-dropdown is calculated on first open.

When I then update my template model that is bound with auto-binding I do get new paper-items but the size of my overlay remains the same size as on first opening.

Is there a way to get a auto-resize on model change for such overlays?

This is my code:

```
<div class="toolbar toolbar-1" layout horizontal center>
  <paper-menu-button icon="settings-cell">
    <template repeat="{{devices}}">
      <paper-item>{{devicename}}</paper-item>
    </template>
  </paper-menu-button> 
</div>

<script>

scope = document.querySelector('template[is=auto-binding]');

scope.devices = [{"devicename": "No device"}];
</script>
```

When I then manually change scope.devices to `[{"devicename": "No device"}, {"devicename": "Device 1"}]` and already have opened the menu before, I have to scroll in the overlay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got answer from IRC:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello World</title>
  <script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-menu-button/paper-menu-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-icons/core-icons.html">
  <polymer-element name="x-test">
    <template>
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      <paper-menu-button id="a" icon="menu">
        <template repeat="{{devices}}">
          <paper-item>{{devicename}}</paper-item>
        </template>
      </paper-menu-button>
      <button on-tap="{{add}}">Add</button>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer('x-test', {
        devices: [{devicename: "abc"}, {devicename: "def"}],
        add: function() {
          this.devices.push({devicename: "more"});

          var el = this.querySelector("::shadow paper-menu-button::shadow core-dropdown::shadow core-dropdown-overlay");
          el.target.style.width = null;
          el.target.style.height = null;
        },
        created: function() {
          this.title = document.title;
        }
      });
    </script>
  </polymer-element>
</head>
<body>
  <x-test></x-test>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems to be a bug in core-dropdown-overlay. resetting target.style.width and height seems to make it work.

Comment: For more information on this, see also the following ticket: https://github.com/Polymer/paper-dropdown/issues/2